# is it possible to re-sort a linq IQueryable in memory?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I am trying to allow resorting of items in a listbox databound to a linq entity result set in memory.  Entity records are structured like:

```
public class DisplayEntity
{
    public int IDPK { get; set; }
    public int OrderInt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

they are loaded and sorted by an integer column in a form load method and factor method:

```
IQueryable<DisplayEntity> entitylist = null;
private void WindowForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entitylist = from e in dbcontext select e;
    RefreshList();
}
private void RefreshList()
{
    entitylist = entitylist.OrderBy(e => e.OrderInt); //order by
    dbcontext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges, entitylist);
    listBoxEntities.DataSource = entitylist;
}
```

The first time the dataset is loaded it sorts correctly, but a subsequent data change and RefreshList() call does not reorder the entitylist.

```
private void ChangeOrder(int argIDPK, int argNewPosition)
{
    DisplayEntity tempe = (from e in entitylist where e.IDPK == argIDPK select e).First();
    tempe.OrderInt = argNewPosition;
    RefreshList();
}
```

I believe the problem with my code is around the OrderBy not working with in-memory linq results or the databinding because changing the name of one of the entitylist entities in memory by similar to using the ChangeOrder method does show the changed name after a RefreshList() call.

Comment: even using two IQueryable<DisplayEntity> sets: the first to store the totally unsorted initial db result (hopefully w/ changes later) and the second to store the initial db result sorted for databinding doesn't sort correctly into the second set after the first sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remember that `entityList` is a query - it's not a simple list of entities in memory, and it gets executed over database each time you are 'sorting' it or search some entity. At the same time Linq to Sql tracks objects which was returned from database. And if entity with same Id exists in memory, it is re-used for new queries results.

So, here is what happens:

```
private void WindowForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entitylist = dbcontext.Entities; // SELECT * FROM Entities
    RefreshList();
}

private void ChangeOrder(int argIDPK, int argNewPosition)
{
    // SELECT TOP(1) * FROM Entities WHERE IDPK = @argIDPK
    // query is executed here
    DisplayEntity tempe = entitylist.First(e => e.IDPK == argIDPK);
    tempe.OrderInt = argNewPosition;
    RefreshList();
}

private void RefreshList()
{
    // SELECT * FROM Entities ORDER BY OrderInt
    entitylist = entitylist.OrderBy(e => e.OrderInt);
    dbcontext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges, entitylist);
    // query is executed here
    listBoxEntities.DataSource = entitylist;
}
```

Tricky moment here that entities are returned from database ordered by OrderInt field value from database (i.e. original sorting). But when these query results are mapped to memory objects then instances with changed values are used. **So, you have entities with locally changed values which are sorted in database values order.**

How you can fix that - simply update database value when you are changing it locally:

```
private void ChangeOrder(int argIDPK, int argNewPosition)
{
    DisplayEntity tempe = entitylist.First(e => e.IDPK == argIDPK);
    tempe.OrderInt = argNewPosition;
    dbcontext.SubmitChanges(); // here we update database
    RefreshList();
}
```

Or use in-memory list instead of `IQueryable` here:

```
List<DisplayEntity> entitylist = null;

private void WindowForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // query is executed only here
    entitylist = dbcontext.Entities.OrderBy(e => e.OrderInt).ToList();
    RefreshList();
}

private void RefreshList()
{    
    listBoxEntities.DataSource = entitylist.OrderBy(e => e.OrderInt).ToList();
}

private void ChangeOrder(int argIDPK, int argNewPosition)
{
    DisplayEntity tempe = entitylist.First(e => e.IDPK == argIDPK);
    tempe.OrderInt = argNewPosition;
    RefreshList();
}
```

Comment: Yes! I think using the List<> got it!  I do happen to have set dbcontext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = true; if that makes a difference in SubmitChanges() calls.